# Android devices take upto 10 minutes to acquire cellular reception after boot while roaming

Tags: mobile-network, cellular-radio, network-signal, roaming

When I boot android device having a SIM on roaming it took around 2-10 minutes to get cellular reception. I've tested this on multiple devices, similar behavior.

One interesting thing is, if device is already booted and then I inserted the SIM, it instantly gets cellular reception.

For a non-roaming SIM it works instantly even after boot.

Edit: The SIM provider told us it's an eSIM, though it looks like a regular SIM card.

If you've any explanation on this, could you please share?

Comment: In your "already booted" tests did the phone had internet access through Wifi?

Comment: @Robert No, there was no wifi